# How to retrieve and display data from mongodb using node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

JSON:

```
"name" : "fhj",
"age" : "23",
"gender" : "female",
"sec" : "b",
"username" : "9886666",
"language" : "HINDI",
"method" : "method2",
"timeSlot" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "fromTime" : 12,
    "toTime" : 15
}
```

I use mongoJS for database connectivity.
mycode:

```
db.users.find(function(err,values){
if(err||!values.length)
   console.log("ERROR !!!!");
else
{ 
   var i=0;
   str='[';
   var str;
   values.forEach(function(user){
     if(i==values.length-1)
         str=str+'{ "name" : "' + user.username + '","age" : "'+ user.age +'","gender":"'+user.gender+'","sec":"'+user.sec+'","username":"'+user.username+'","language":"'+user.language+'","method":"'+user.method+'","toTime":"'+user.timeSlot.to+'"}';
     else{
       str = str + '{ "name" : "' + user.username + '","age" : "'+ user.age +'","gender":"'+user.gender+'","sec":"'+user.sec+'","username":"'+user.username+'","language":"'+user.language+'","method":"'+user.method+'","toTime":"'+user.timeSlot.to+'"},' +'\n';
       i++;
     }
      str=JSON.parse(user);

   });
  str = str.trim();
   str = str + ']';
 }  
});
}
```

I want to retrieve and dispaly data from mongodb using node.js which contains json like the above file. how to do that???

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far (the appropriate code snippets) in Node.js?

Comment: use the mongodb driver for node.js (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/)

Comment: @Subham Code goes into the question. The code is unreadable in a comment. Please post more information *into the question*, not into a comment.

Comment: Have you tried the quickstart yet?  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/overview/quickstart/

Comment: No.I'm using mongoJS in me whole project..so please solve it using mongoJS..I can't change driver only for this purpose.

Comment: What doesn't work about your existing code?

Comment: timeslot value is shown "undefined"